# JavaScript switch case

Tags: javascript, html

My JavaScript *switch* case isn't working for some reason, and I can't figure it out.

I am trying to display a certain input only of a certain option is chosen:

```
function showHideSchools(obj){

    var curSel = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value

    switch(curSel)
    {
        case '0-2':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="none"
            break;
        case '3-5':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;
        case '6-8':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;
        case '9-11':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;
        case '12-14':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;
        case '15-16':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;
        case '17-18':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;
        case '19 and over':
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
            break;

        default:
            document.getElementById('schools').style.display="none"
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="childrenAges">Ages of children still living at home: </label>
    <select name="childrenAges" id="childrenAges" onchange="showHideSchools(this);">
        <option>Select one</option>
        <option value="0-2">0-2</option>
        <option value="3-5">3-5</option>
        <option value="6-8">6-8</option>
        <option value="9-11">9-11</option>
        <option value="12-14">12-14</option>
        <option value="15-16">15-16</option>
        <option value="17-18">17-18</option>
        <option value="19 and over">19 and over</option>
    </select>
</p>

<div id="schools" style="display:none">
    <p>
        <label for="schoolName">What school/s do they attend: </label>
        <input type="text" name="schoolName" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "isn't working".  What's the desired result and the actual result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a *switch* case:

```
if(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value != "Select one" && obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value != "0-2"){
    document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block";
}else{
    document.getElementById('schools').style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Display is none on "0-2" as well.

Comment: He may intent to do different things depending on what option was selected at some point. At least, that's the only reason I can fathom for all those redundant case blocks.

Comment: @Josh : you're right I didn't see that one. You can add a OR statement
@no : couldn't guess that ;)

Comment: Yup, what no said. This is just the preliminary "Get it to work" phase, I will try and clean up the code and make it more efficient once I have gotten it to work as intended.

Comment: You shouldn't access the drop down with `document.getElementById("childrenAges")` (especially not twice). Providing a reference as a parameter as kielie did is better.

Comment: OMG ! Playing to much with jQuery and you'll forget any simple JS !

Answer (score 5):

As others said, your `case` tests didn't match the `value` of the first three options.

There isn't any reason to repeat that line `document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block";` over and over. Just let all the conditions that lead to that outcome fall through to a single line with that instruction.

```
function showHideSchools (obj) {

  var curSel = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;

  switch (curSel) {
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '9-11':
    case '12-14':
    case '15-16':
    case '17-18':
    case '19 and over':
      document.getElementById('schools').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case '1':
    default:
      document.getElementById('schools').style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` of the options `0-2`, `3-5` and `6-8` are `1`, `2` and `3`, respectively.

You have them as `0-2`, `3-5` and `6-8` in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, that was a typo, that wasn't what I had in my file.

Answer (score 1):

> 0-2
>    3-5
>    6-8

> case '0-2':
> case '3-5':

Your values and case parameters do not correspond. When you select '0-2', *.value* is "1".

Answer (score 0):

The case values are wrong. They have to match the `value` in the `<option>` tags, not the displayed text.

So they would be

```
case '1':
    document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
      break;
    case '2':
    document.getElementById('schools').style.display="block"
      break;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you'd be better off switching the criteria, so that you hide when the value is `""` and show the box in *all other cases* - that looks like what you're trying to do...?

Other than that, I'm not 100% sure what your problem is, but if the problem is that it's not working for the first three items, then the reason is that their values will be `1`, `2` and `3`, not `0-2` etc, that you're testing for.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working with a simple if statement, if(curSel=="yes") {...etc}else{...etc} but when I try to implement the switch it just WONT work, even though I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the `option` values, rather their representation in `switch`. For example:

```
case '0-2':
```

There is nothing like that in the select's option values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    case '1':
    ...
    case '2':
    ...
    case '3':
    ...
    case '9-11':
    ...
    case '12-14':
    ...
```

I.e., you should check the content of option's **value** attribute, not text inside <option></option> tags.